# Question about De Moivre's method and e

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, polar-coordinates, euler-mascheroni-constant

i was looking at an example and it stated this:

$e^{i(α+β)} = (\cosα\cosβ−\sinα\sinβ)+i(\sinα\cosβ+\cos α\sin β)$

using de moivre's method:
$\cos(α+β)+i\sin(α+β)=(\cosα\cosβ−\sinα\sinβ)+i(\sinα\cosβ+\cosα\sinβ)$

i am a bit unsure of how $e^{i(α+β)} = \cos(α+β)+i\sin(α+β)$ and am looking for a point in the right direction. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is because
$$e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x.$$

Indeed observe what happens when you expand out both sides of the
identity
$$e^{i(x+y)}=e^{ix} e^{iy}.$$

Comment: i thought that was apart of eulers formula, not de moivre's method though? or did i read my text book to late at night haha.